# Why did they use single and not double quotes in this news headline?

Tags: grammar, writing, quotation-marks

> '[King Charles](https://www.ok.co.uk/royal/king-charles-monarchy-buckingham-palace-30921600?utm_source=flipboard&utm_content=OK_Magazine%2Fmagazine%2FOK%21%20magazine) should feel justified - he's defied predictions the
> monarchy would crumble'

Comment: The body of your question doesn't contain a question.  Make sure that the body of you question contains a question, and all the context.  And the title of your question contains a brief descriptive summary.

Comment: Is your question "why did they use **single** and not double quotes" or "why did they use quotes at all?"  Make your question clear!

Comment: Why did they use single and not double quotes?

Comment: Ok please fix the body and title of your question by including the question and the clarification in the body of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The journalist is quoting Jennie Bond (an expert on the Royal Family).

Both single and double quotation marks may be used to indicate direct quotations. There is no difference in meaning.  Possibly double quotation marks would have seemed too big and heavy in the bold font used for the headline.